# BACKUP DATABASE WITH COMPRESSION is not supported on Web Edition (64-bit)

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting the error

```
BACKUP DATABASE WITH COMPRESSION is not supported on Web Edition (64-bit)
```

while doing this query that **NOT contains the WITH COMPRESSION** clause:

```
BACKUP DATABASE bfsdfsdf
       TO  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\blablabla.bak' 
       WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,
       NAME = N'blablabla-Full Database Backup', 
       SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

I'm doing the query in SSMS installed on the server.
I'm using SQL Server 2008 Web edition, and I know that this edition don't support backup compression, **but in my query I'm not requesting compression**!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved changing the file name.

The default was NO_COMPRESSION but the .bak file already existed and was a compressed one (created on another local machine with SQL standard, and then copied on this server). In this case the default is always with compression. I discovered because putting no_compression leads me to another error saying the media is compressed.

Changing file name or deleting .bak file solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

The server has a default compression setting that is used if you don't specify an option in your `BACKUP` statement. (Why it might allow you to set compression-by-default if your edition doesn't support it I have no idea; unfortunately I don't have a Web edition to test that theory).

Try adding `WITH NO_COMPRESSION` to your statement.

Answer (score -1):

This simply shows Compression is not supported on MSSQL Web Edition

```
Msg 1844, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
BACKUP DATABASE WITH COMPRESSION is not supported on Web Edition (64-bit).

Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Comment: I don't think so, the asker actually provided an answer that solved the problem

Comment: Downvote reason: You didn't read the question.